# Loading NSURLRequest on webView from a different class.

Tags: ios, webview, properties, uiwebview, synthesize

I created a view controller with a webView in the storyboard called GoogleSearchController. The property for the webView was, of course, declared in the GoogleSearchController.

I am attempting to access the synthesized webView property, which is *googleWebView, within the MapViewController, so that I can append my point annotations to a google search. The output here is correct. I'm getting the appended and desired URL, but I'm failing to actually load it. At the end of the leftButtonAnnotationPressed method, you will notice I try to call loadRequest on self.classObj.googleWebView. Something is not going as it should. This is the first time I've tried to use @synthesize, and I'm open to all suggestions.

My question comes in two parts. A: am I using @synthesize as it is intended? and B: If this is the proper use, why won't my webView load the request?

## GoogleSearchController.h

```
 @interface GoogleSearchController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *googleWebView;

 @end
```

## GoogleSearchController.m

```
@synthesize googleWebView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.googleWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    self.googleWebView.delegate = self;
}
```

## MapViewController.m

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GoogleSearchController *classObj;

-(void)leftButtonAnnotationPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"googleSearch" sender:nil];
self.classObj = [[GoogleSearchController alloc] init]; <--------

MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [self.mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:([self.mapView.selectedAnnotations count]) -1];
NSString *appendString = annotation.title;
NSString *googleString = @"http://www.google.com/search?q=";
NSString *appendedUrlString = [googleString stringByAppendingString:appendString];

if ([appendedUrlString containsString:@" "]) {
    appendedUrlString = [appendedUrlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:appendedUrlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.classObj.googleWebView loadRequest:request];<------

    NSLog(@"appended string: %@", request);

}
```

Comment: I noticed you declared the UIWebView as an IBOutlet and then initialized it in viewDidLoad. Is the UIWebView created in IB or are you programmatically creating it?

Comment: The UIWebView was created in the storyboard using IB, so you're spot on here - I have not created it programmatically.

Comment: So why are you re-initializing it in viewDidLoad? Comment out the init line and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that and It doesn't work

Comment: I've been use to doing this stuff programmatically, so the initialization is just habit. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well one reason its not working is because you are reassigning a new googlwWebVIew when you already have it defined in your nib. Did you connect the IBOutlet to the respective UIWebview in your nib?

Comment: Also are any of the UIWebviewDelegate methods being called?

Comment: As of right now that's all I have for the webView. I'm a pretty new developer. A student in fact, so if there is something I'm doing wrong please let me know. I haven't used @synthesize before, so really I'm just wondering if I'm using the right approach. I needed to access that property in a different view controller (MapViewController) where I'm appending the annotation title to the search. The webView is a property of GoogleSearchController, that was set up in the storyboard. No delegate methods are being called. I just need to load the NSURLRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the NSURLRequest in a data source seemed to be a fairly simple solution. In DataSource.h, all we did was declare a public property of type NSURLRequest *searchURL.

```
+(instancetype) sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLRequest *searchURL;
```

The sharedInstance is going to be used for our singleton pattern, which ensures we only get one instance of our DataSource. In DataSource.m, we'll implement our sharedInstance like this: (which for the post part is text book).

```
+ (instancetype) sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

That's all we need to store our NSURLRequest.

Within the MapViewController we use our sharedInstance to access the NSURLRequest property from within the DataSource and set it equal to the appended NSURLRequest.

```
- (void) leftAnnotationButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [self.mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:([self.mapView.selectedAnnotations count]) -1];
        NSString *appendString = annotation.title;
        NSString *googleString = @"http://www.google.com/search?q=";
        NSString *appendedUrlString = [googleString stringByAppendingString:appendString];

        if ([appendedUrlString containsString:@" "]) {
            appendedUrlString = [appendedUrlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:appendedUrlString];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [DataSource sharedInstance].searchURL = request;  <----
            NSLog(@"appended string: %@", request);
        }

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"googleSearch" sender:nil];
}
```

All that is left is to load the webView. This can be done in view did load in the GoogleSearchController where this property resides. (which removes all of the headache).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.googleWebView loadRequest:[DataSource sharedInstance].searchURL];
}
```

All we are doing here is simply calling loadRequest on our webView with the NSURLRequest that is now stored in our DataSource. And we are finished. I love this approach, and I hope anybody else reading this does to. You even get a little lesson on singletons and a data source.

Answer (score 1):

`@sythesize` is not required/mandatory anymore. Without `@synthesize` iOS/XCode would automatically create an instance variable for you _[propertyName]

If your UIWebView is created in IB, you need not initialize it programatically. Make sure your webView and the ViewController IBOutlet property are connected. That should suffice.

The important reason that i can think for your request not loading is because your loading the url in a different instance than the one that is displayed in your `GoogleSearchViewController`

You are doing this

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"googleSearch" sender:nil];
self.classObj = [[GoogleSearchController alloc] init]; <--------
```

in the first line, you are asking storyboard to perform a segue. So, story board will create an instance of the view controller with views and all the subviews and display.

In the second line, you are creating your own instance of the view controller.. Who is displaying it? -- No one.

Your loading the url in the wrong instance.

Ok now, how do i gain access to the view controller that is being displayed?

Xcode/iOS gives you an option to do that with `prepareForSegue` you can access the VC and the webview like shown below to load the request.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"googleSearch"]){
        GoogleSearchViewController *vc = nil;
        if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
            UINavigationController *navVC = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            vc = (GoogleSearchViewController *)navVC.viewControllers[0];
        }else{
            vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        }
        if(vc){
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:appendedUrlString];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [vc.googleWebView loadRequest:request];

        }
    }

}
```

Would be interested to know if this worked for you

Comment: Hey I appreciate it! I'm testing this out now.

Comment: I really don't mean to bother you, but say we remove:

Comment: self.classObj = [[GoogleSearchController alloc] init]; There must be an easier solution of accessing the webView property I created in the storyboard within the MapViewController. This just seems far too complicated.

Comment: if I use the prepareForSegue: as an identifier for the button, the app terminates.

Comment: you cannot used `prepareForSegue` as a selector for button.. It is a method that gets invoked by iOS after you  do this `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"googleSearch" sender:nil];`  you may want to read the documentation  [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:)

Comment: Sounds good, and I appreciate the help! I did find a different solution to the problem that you may want to take a look at. It's far easier than the approach we were working on before. I'll have it up by the end of the night.

Comment: I just posted my answer, and I would really like to know what you thought about it? I think it's pretty slick, but I'm also relatively new to this stuff. Let me know what you think, and thanks again for sticking it out with me.